# iPhone 3G communication app

Tags: iphone, ios, sim

I have an iPhone 3G running iOS 4.2.1 that I recently restored to factory settings. I have been using it mostly as an iPod, because I can't find any communication apps for it. I tried putting in a modern SIM card (it was the big size card), and it didn't recognize it. Is there a way I could use a SIM card or an app to text/call over WiFi? What app could this be, and where can I find it? The phone doesn't connect to the App Store so I have to sideload. It is not jailbroken but could be if necessary.

Comment: The SIM card doesn’t work likely because your carrier has or is in the process of killing off 3G.  I know AT&T will not allow “new” (as in new to the carrier, not newly made) 3G device provisions.  They still support 3G for legacy apps and have grandfathered some accounts for transition.  As for apps, I highly doubt you’ll find one.  There’s no incentive to maintain something that was last updated over 4 years ago (2019)

Comment: 3 out of the UK's 'big four' have already started switching their networks off. Completion expected next year, so it's doubtful anyone's going to sell you a new 3G capable service now.

Comment: Here’s a project that will allow you to create your own 3G network which means you’ll be able to make phone calls between devices (on that network) and if you connect to a SIP trunk, anywhere in the world.  See:  https://www.technologyreview.com/2010/04/20/91755/build-your-own-cellular-network/